# Unknown command line flag compression

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to export tables from BQ to CS using the command-line tool.
i followed the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

I tried to run the example script:

```
 extract --compression=GZIP 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare' gs://my_bucket/shakespeare.zip
```

I keep getting:

```
Error parsing command: Unknown command line flag 'compression'
```

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I just run below and it perfectly worked for me

```
bq extract --compression=GZIP bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare gs://my_bucket/shakespeare.zip
```

it also worked with double quotes around full qualified table name, but not with single quotes (as it is in link in your question)

Comment: I still get the error. What is your gsutil version?

Comment: gsutil version: 4.19;